# Remote Data Replication

Tags: php, mysql, database, replication

Greetings Everyone

We have a mysql database running on our localhost. In that we have a table called xyz. We also need the same database to be running online. Whats the best way we can replicate? The database will be updated locally.

Additionally, there is a field in the online xyz table called 'visits'. We wouldn't want to overwrite this particular field in the online table.

Now the records can be huge in number. My boss suggested we write a php script that copies records to the online database and flags the records that are copied. This way we do not copy twice. I know this might not be the best idea. What if a records is deleted in the online database?

Thanking You
Imran

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysql's replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) - it's the right tool for the job and will save you a lot of headaches.

If you start the servers with --replicate-wild-ignore-table=dbname.visits then that table will not be replicated.

> What if a records is deleted in the online database?

Don't. Revoke delete privileges on the relevant tables and use a state flag instead. Although replication will handle such cases, it'll save a lot of pain in the long run.

Comment: my boss has asked me to not use mysql's replication

Answer (score 0):

The latest phpmyadmin has some features like this build in.